Running an application with Qt 6.7 on Android reduced functionalities for QList
I am creating an application that will search for Bluetooth devices and then connect to one sensor of mine and display the sensor data. I have my main widget, and the search of the devices happens in a second widget. I built my application first with MSVC2019 and in my Computer (Windows 11) it can do everything (I have the Qt6.7 version).
Now, I tried to run it in my Android device (With Clang arm64-v8a), but there are some features that are not working as they were in the desktop app. I also tried setting a list in the MainWidget, but I have the same problems. The main one is the QList:

When I press on my button, nothing happens, it should be clearing the list and adding a new item.
I simply can not select any items.
My layout makes everything go to the left after opening the widget

I get the following warning:

(:-1: warning: Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.)

scanwindow.h:
#ifndef SCANWINDOW_H
#define SCANWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent>
#include <QBluetoothDeviceInfo>
#include <QLowEnergyController>
#include <QListWidgetItem>

namespace Ui {
class ScanWindow;
}

class ScanWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ScanWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~ScanWindow();

private slots:
    void on_startScanButton_clicked();
    void deviceDiscovered(const QBluetoothDeviceInfo &device);
    void on_deviceList_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item);
    void on_connectButton_clicked();

    void on_clearButton_clicked();

signals:
    void characteristicValueChanged(const QString &value);
    void deviceSelected(const QBluetoothDeviceInfo &device);

private:
    Ui::ScanWindow *ui;
    QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent *discoveryAgent;
    QBluetoothDeviceInfo selectedDevice;
    QList<QLowEnergyService*> services;
};

#endif

scanwindow.cpp:
#include "scanwindow.h"
#include "ui_scanwindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QPermissions>
#include <QCoreApplication>

ScanWindow::ScanWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::ScanWindow)
    , discoveryAgent(new QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent(this))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->connectButton->setDisabled(true);

    connect(discoveryAgent, &QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::deviceDiscovered, this, &ScanWindow::deviceDiscovered);
}

ScanWindow::~ScanWindow()
{

    qDeleteAll(services);
    services.clear();

    delete ui;

}

void ScanWindow::on_startScanButton_clicked()
{
    ui->deviceList->clear();

#if QT_CONFIG(permissions)
    QBluetoothPermission permission;
    permission.setCommunicationModes(QBluetoothPermission::Access);

    switch (qApp->checkPermission((permission))) {
    case Qt::PermissionStatus::Undetermined:
        qDebug() << "Undetermined";
        qApp->requestPermission(permission, this,  &ScanWindow::on_startScanButton_clicked);
    break;
    case Qt::PermissionStatus::Denied:
        qDebug() << "Denied";
    break;
    case Qt::PermissionStatus::Granted:
        qDebug() << "Granted";
    break;

    }
#endif

    discoveryAgent->setLowEnergyDiscoveryTimeout(15000);
    discoveryAgent->start(QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::LowEnergyMethod);
}

void ScanWindow::deviceDiscovered(const QBluetoothDeviceInfo &device){

    if (device.coreConfigurations() & QBluetoothDeviceInfo::LowEnergyCoreConfiguration) {
        qDebug() << "Added";
        QString label = device.name();
        QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem(label, ui->deviceList);
        item->setData(Qt::UserRole,QVariant::fromValue(device));
    }

}

void ScanWindow::on_deviceList_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item) {
    QBluetoothDeviceInfo device = item->data(Qt::UserRole).value<QBluetoothDeviceInfo>();

    selectedDevice = device;

    ui->connectButton->setEnabled(true);

    qDebug() << "Selected device:" << device.name() << device.address().toString();
}

void ScanWindow::on_connectButton_clicked()
{
    if(!selectedDevice.isValid()){
        qDebug() << "No device selected or device info is invalid";
        return;
    }

    emit deviceSelected(selectedDevice);
}

void ScanWindow::on_clearButton_clicked()
{
    ui->deviceList2->clear();
    new QListWidgetItem(tr("Oak2"), ui->deviceList2);
    ui->deviceList2->repaint();
    ui->deviceList2->updateGeometry();
    ui->deviceList2->update();
    QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);
}

I tried to repaint the widget, process the events, and to update. None of these work.
